# MacOS Monterrey will not run shell scripts

Tags: bash, script, macos

I use shell scripts a lot. Ever since upgrading to OS Monterrey 12.3.1, none of my shell scripts will run.  They are in the same locations they were before the upgrade to Monterrey.

I execute a shell script simply by typing it's name in bash terminal from within the script's directory, and pressing enter:

```
~ cd /path/to/shellscript
~ shellscriptname [enter]
```

In Big Sur, the script would run and the files would get copied, but in Monterrey,

```
 command not found
```

is returned.  There are no errors - just this response.

For example, I have a shell script named `copyTestFiles`, which contains copy commands like so:

```
cp /path/fileA /path/fileAcopy
cp /path/fileB /path/fileBcopy
cp /path/fileC /path/fileCcopy
```

where the scripts are set for execution

```
-rwxr-xr-x
```

I can run each of the commands within the script individually from the command line, but not the script itself.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your original question with details so it can be reviewed and reopened. Posting a new question looses all the comments/feedback you got, making it more difficult to understand what's going on.

Comment: @nohillside  Then don't close the question, ask for clarity.

Comment: There is a long list of comments beneath the original questions, doing exactly that. And we routinely put questions on hold which require clarifications, to avoid getting half-baked answers based on (wrong) assumptions.